# Convert SMS from text to PDU format Java

Tags: sms, java

Is there any java library for encoding mobile short messages from text to PDU format?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I used [smsj](http://smsj.sourceforge.net/) and found it very designed and working fine. It allows constructing complex SMS messages without dealing with gory details of PDU.